# Alter Exchange 2007 attachments server side

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

Can I hook into exchange 2007 to monitor attachments and alter them.  Ultimately my desire is to change the codec of a .wav file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All incoming attachments? You would have to write a 'sink' in Exchange. Sinks allow you to tap into incoming messages/outgoing messages etc-this is how most applications do incoming spam filtering and compliance audits.